# How to mock HttpContext in C# using FakeITEasy

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I have something like this one of the methods I am testing

Here Constants is a separate sealed class, I want to set the Constants.UserPhone to a custom value..Is that possible?

```
if(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment.ContainsKey(Constants.UserPhone))
          userPhone= HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment[Constants.UserPhone].ToString();
```

Comment: Not if it is a constant. If it is not a constant or readonly property, then you can, but you should remove it from that class if so.

Comment: I can try to set it in a unittest? Is that possible?

Comment: Not if it is a constant (`const`) or a read-only (`readonly`) field or a getter only property.